# how to pass values from List View Adapter to fragment in android

Tags: android, fragment, adapter

I want to pass same value from adapter to fragment and I send it in next way:

```
Fragment fr = new Fragment 

fr.deleteMothod(Position);
```

when I call above code , it is creating new instance of Fragment therefore I am not accessing values of fragment.
How to use old instance of fragment.

Comment: NotificationActivity sct = (NotificationActivity)activity; this code is used to use old instance of notification activity ,  similar how to use old instance of fragment

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the constructor of your fragment like so:

```
 public static DetailsFragment newInstance(String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        DetailsFragment detailsFragment = new DetailsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("selection", selection);
        args.putStringArray("selectionArgs", selectionArgs);
        detailsFragment.setArguments(args);
        return detailsFragment;
    }
```

However there is a much better way of doing this, if you use an interface.

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve your fragment from the Fragment manager by id or tag, then call the method on it. 
These are the official docs http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Deliver

Comment: In the sample, google is using SupportFragmentManager and SupportFragments, in your code you are using simple (non support) fragments...  
Try to use getFragmentManager instead  
    ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);